# Appexchart combine bubble and line chart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts, bubble-chart

I am using Apex Chart JavaScript library to render chart. I am trying to combine or mix bubble and line chart but facing issue I have gone through the document and found we can combine two charts in apex chart so I have taken an example and try to combine bubble and line chart but facing an issue in my example line chart is generated but bubbles not. I have prepared a fiddle please have a look and help me out

'https://jsfiddle.net/niteshabhi_01/rt20uLng/4/'

Thank You

Comment: you can draw multiple charts. make a separate options/series json and assign it to another div.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but if generate multiple charts and then overlap it over one then I won't be able to perform any event on the chart which is rendered behind the line graph in my case